# Как использовать 2 стора в EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

в `extjs` использую `widget.accordion` и там у меня 4 поля. 3 из них использует `storeA` а четвертый `storeB`.

```
initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                hideCollapseTool: true,
                columnLines: true,
                viewConfig: {
                    stripeRows: true
                },
                store: 'TelCatalogStore',
                columns: [{
                    text     : 'ID',
                    flex     : 1,
                    sortable : true,
                    dataIndex: 'id'
                }, {
                    text     : 'Наименования',
                    sortable : false,
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                }, {
                    text     : 'Номер',
                    sortable : false,
                    dataIndex: 'nomer'
                },
                    //тут storeB 
                {
                    text     : 'Статус',
                    width    : 75,
                    sortable : false,
                    renderer : this.changeRenderer,
                    dataIndex: 'status'
                }]
            }]
        });
        this.callParent();
    }
```

Как это реализовать?!

Answer (score 3):

С точки зрения Sencha стор должен быть один. Если надо два, то лучше склеить данные на сервере. В качестве хака можно склеить несколько сторов в один, но встроеного для этого ничего нет, надо будет все писать самостоятельно. Например можно склеивать данные из нескольких запросов. Но архитектурно правильно все равно заниматься этим на стороне сервера.

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?251169-Creating-one-grid-view-with-multiple-stores